Is Rocco the judas who allowed the hit attempt on Michael, then killed the assassins?
I made the mistake of seeing The Godfather II on TV and obviously can't turn away once you know it's there to watch.
I understand the overall gist of the failed assassination attempt on Michael Corleone after the party in Nevada at the start of the film—Hyman Roth is behind it, using Johnny Ola to turn Fredo into an (unwitting?) asset.
But based on Michael's conversation with Tom Hagen while the compound is on lockdown, with everyone out searching for the assassins, it's certainly implied someone close in the Corleone Family played a part in the betrayal.
I doubt this is referring to Fredo, who just doesn't seem capable of having knowledge his brother's life is endangered and not spilling the beans, let alone being the sort of cold-blooded killer and strategist to realize he needs to find and kill the hitmen before Michael can interrogate them.
Fredo's betrayal seems more... unintentional. I believe Fredo would never intentionally conspire to hurt his Family or help an enemy harm Michael. But Fredo not being smart enough to realize he shouldn't reveal sensitive info like which cabin Michael sleeps in or his schedule while drinking with Johnny Ola? Absolutely.
There's also the scene where Michael specifically instructs Rocco to retrieve the assassins ALIVE.... I mean, obviously he'd want to reiterate that to a bunch of hot-headed mafiosos seeking revenge on enemies who just attacked their boss. But the fact Michael specifically addresses Rocco when demanding they be brought back alive feels important.
In my opinion, the only solid options are Al Neri or Rocco, and due to Neri still being close to Michael and a crucial part of The Godfather III, I assume it wasn't Al.
Rocco is also a longtime Corleone Family member, and there's nothing obvious in the film(s) that indicates Rocco is anything less than completely loyal.
I never put this together, but it always struck me as weird.... Rocco is a trusted hitter, a guy who will accept any task without question.... so why does Michael let/allow Rocco to basically suicide-mission himself to kill Hyman Roth in the airport near the end?
As a kid, I assumed he bungled the attempt on Roth in Cuba and thus it was his mistake to correct, even if it meant his life.
But Rocco just seems like too critical an asset to Michael and the Corleone Family to throw away like that—the only possible outcomes of that hit were being killed immediately or being arrested.
Even if Rocco is the most trusted Corleone hitter, shooting a guy at point-blank range in police custody at the airport isn't exactly rocket science, and any number of low-level, expendable thugs could have been used.... Rocco is seemingly #2/3 under Michael and Al Neri at that point (unless Rocco was used specifically to have a familiar face in the assassination montage à la The Godfather).
I've read the books and seen all of the films a ton, so I don't think I'm missing any crucial evidence.... Are there any other obvious suspects for the Nevada assassination turncoat?
